# Flow Abstract Type and Function - Property cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, function, flowtype

I'm using flow with react native and I must be missing something.

I tried to express my issue with words but there's no way it doesn't get really confusing so here is the situation:
[Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCiAbngHYZgC8YAzhgE4CWZA5gNya4EDKArgCNaAY2YC8DamAA8ABQB8AChwBDBioC2tAFxhZASmrywAuHBh4VZTl3x61AawAiKjCqkBvAL6dsd2Y48eBbCGHgAJiTkGAHqWp6oYElgqgwOAPq0wXihEbqxzq4qqD7oFpRwZAVBIWHhuvxCokzikjRygdm5kaQUsZq0SqkD+Z21EVF9agP6uqbmlmRGYB6JyUnClbQLAHTwrMrTWjupGVnj4fqc60kMeBh8DEuMfHicXuhAA)

I've been fiddling around this for a while but couldn't quite figure out why can't I use the property that I defined!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write the code as either

```
type Subscriber<P> = (params: P) => boolean;

type ParkSelectedEventParams = {
    park_selected: {}
};

let onParkSelected: Subscriber<ParkSelectedEventParams> = (params: ParkSelectedEventParams): boolean => {
      console.log(params.park_selected);
      return true;
};
```

([On Flow Play](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCiAbngHYZgC8YAzhgE4CWZA5gNya4EDKArgCNaAY2YC8DADwAFAHzUwAChwBDBioC2tAFxhpASmryBcODDwqynLvj1qA1gBEVGFQoDeAX07Zb0hzx45sIYeAAmJOQY-upaHqhgiWCqDPYA+rRBeCHhujFOLiqo3ujmlHBk+YHBoWG6-EKiTOJSVVk5EaQUMZq08jTKar15Ae21kd1DWvq6JmYWZEZg7glJicIVtPMAdPCsg7G02ynpmTXh+pxriQx4GHwMi4x8eJwlqEA))

or I believe you can trim down the last part to

```
let onParkSelected: Subscriber<*> = (params: ParkSelectedEventParams): boolean => {
      console.log(params.park_selected);
      return true;
};
```

since the function declaration part allows Flow to know how to fill in the `*`.

Comment: That changed a lot of things in my app but it works now, I'll have to re-read this a bunch of times to understand why did I get it wrong to begin with and why is it better like this ;) Cheers

Comment: You can just `let onParkSelected: Subscriber<ParkSelectedEventParams> = params => { / * etc */ }` , since `Subscriber` already annotates the function itself.

Comment: @kalley Yep, that's certainly an option too.